# How to remove the indentation after the optimization problem

Tags: indentation, ieeeconf, optidef

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
}

\maketitle

\section{Test}
The optimization problem is formulated as
\begin{mini!}|l|[3]
    {w}{f(w)+ R(w+6x) \protect\label{eq:ObjectiveExample1}}
    {\label{eq:Example1}}
    {y=}
    \addConstraint{g(w)}{=0;\quad\protect\label{eq:C1Example3}}{\text{first constraint}}
    \addConstraint{n(w)}{= 6;\quad\protect\label{eq:C2Example1}}{\text{second constraint}}
    \addConstraint{L(w)+r(x)}{=Kw+p;\quad\protect\label{eq:C3Example1}}{\text{third constraint}}
\end{mini!}
where $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc,
$a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, and $a$ is abc.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As seen in the figure, there is an indentation before 'where'.
I actually do not know why the indentation appears.
Is there any method to remove the indentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `optidef` package suffers from ***many*** unprotected end-of-lines, creating unwanted spaces.

For the present problem a fix would be to define more efficiently an internal environment.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{optidef}

\RenewEnviron{BaseMiniExclam}[7]{%
  \selectConstraintMult{#1}%
  \renewcommand{\localOptimalVariable}{#2}%
  \begin{subequations}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{b}}{\allowdisplaybreaks}%
  #4
  \begin{alignat}{5}
    \bodyobj{#2}{#3}{#6}{#5}
    \BODY
  \end{alignat}
  \end{subequations}%
  \setStandardMini
}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
}

\maketitle

\section{Test}
The optimization problem is formulated as
\begin{mini!}|l|[3]
    {w}{f(w)+ R(w+6x) \protect\label{eq:ObjectiveExample1}}
    {\label{eq:Example1}}
    {y=}
    \addConstraint{g(w)}{=0;\quad\protect\label{eq:C1Example3}}{\text{first constraint}}
    \addConstraint{n(w)}{= 6;\quad\protect\label{eq:C2Example1}}{\text{second constraint}}
    \addConstraint{L(w)+r(x)}{=Kw+p;\quad\protect\label{eq:C3Example1}}{\text{third constraint}}
\end{mini!}
where $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc,
$a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, and $a$ is abc.

\end{document}
```

I used `newtx` because I can't stand Computer Modern math and Times text.

[image]

Comment: I will solve the problem using the same way as your suggestion, without changing`optidef`. Thank you.

Comment: In my original optimization problem, some constraints have 3 terms, e.g. $\lVert x_i-x_j\rVert\le d_{th};\quad x_i,x_j\in\mathcal{X};\quad \mathcal{X}\in f(t)$. In this case, is there any method to vertically align the third terms?

Comment: @Danny_Kim This is a whole new question.

Comment: Dear @egreg, do you know any good resource where I can learn more about unprotected end-of-lines and unwanted spaces? I am the main developer of the optidef package and I would like to correct this issue. I think that the issue should be corrected using the % character at the end of lines, however I am not able to successfully achieve that within the optidef package. For example, in the original BaseMiniExclam environment, if you want to keep the double if structure with the begingroup and endgroup commands, how can you protect the end of lines?

Comment: @egreg If it helps, perhaps we could continue the discussion in https://github.com/jeslago/optidef/issues/19, or I could open a new question in tex.stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to tell why it happens. I suspect it's something related to the definition of `mini!`, and that it has some unwanted spaces in its `\end` definition. Anyways, telling LaTeX that we want a new paragraph without indentation seems to solve the problem: `\par\noindent`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
}

\maketitle

\section{Test}
The optimization problem is formulated as
\begin{mini!}|l|[3]
    {w}{f(w)+ R(w+6x) \protect\label{eq:ObjectiveExample1}}
    {\label{eq:Example1}}
    {y=}
    \addConstraint{g(w)}{=0;\quad\protect\label{eq:C1Example3}}{\text{first constraint}}
    \addConstraint{n(w)}{= 6;\quad\protect\label{eq:C2Example1}}{\text{second constraint}}
    \addConstraint{L(w)+r(x)}{=Kw+p;\quad\protect\label{eq:C3Example1}}{\text{third constraint}}
\end{mini!}
 \par\noindent where $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc,
$a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, $a$ is abc, and $a$ is abc.

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should never need `\noindent` in latex so this is really a workaround for the broken package definition also note it suppresses indentation but not other features of the start of a paragraph such as vertical space if `\parskip` is non zero.

Comment: Wow, `\par\noindent` readily works well in my case, but one line is spaced. Anyhow, thank you for me to know the command `\par\noindent`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Did not know that! Thanks!

Comment: @Danny_Kim You should go with the other answer!